# Azure SQL Database Bacpac Local Restore does not work anymore

Tags: sql-server, azure, restore, bacpac

I have a SQL azure instance with: SQL2014 RTM SQL Azure 12.0.2000.8 and i'm using SSMS to export to a local bacpac file. next, i'm trying to import this into a local SQL server instance (SQL2014 SP1 Developer Edition (64-bit) 12.0.4232.0).

This used to work just fine, however, recently it stopped working. (i'm not aware of any updates, but well... maybe something *got* updated.)

When trying to import, i get this: (translation below)

### German error msg:

Das Paket konnte nicht importiert werden.
Warning SQL0: Bei einem Projekt, das "Microsoft Azure SQL-Datenbank v12" als Zielplattform angibt, können Kompatibilitätsprobleme mit "SQL Server 2014" auftreten.
Warning SQL72012: Das Objekt [die_db_Data] ist im Ziel vorhanden, wird jedoch nicht gelöscht, obwohl Sie das Kontrollkästchen zum Generieren von DROP-Anweisungen für Objekte, die sich in der Zieldatenbank, nicht jedoch in der Quelle befinden, aktiviert haben.
Warning SQL72012: Das Objekt [die_db_Log] ist im Ziel vorhanden, wird jedoch nicht gelöscht, obwohl Sie das Kontrollkästchen zum Generieren von DROP-Anweisungen für Objekte, die sich in der Zieldatenbank, nicht jedoch in der Quelle befinden, aktiviert haben.
Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Meldung 102, Ebene 15, Status 1, Zeile 1 Incorrect syntax near ';'.
Error SQL72045: Fehler bei der Skriptausführung. Ausgeführtes Skript:

### CREATE MASTER KEY;

in english, that basically says:

The packet could not be imported. There might be compatibility problems when SQL database v12 is the target using SQL server 2015.
warning sql72012: the object [some object] is available on the target, but will not be deleted, although DROP has been checked.

### error SQL72014, SQL 72045: Error executing script: CREATE MASTER KEY;

any suggestions on what might be causing this and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're describing might be related to a known issue described in the following blog post (which also includes a workaround):
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqlemea/2017/03/30/exported-database-from-azure-sql-failed-to-be-imported-to-azure-sql-or-to-local-sql-server/

We're currently working on a more permanent solution.

Regards,

Gilad Mittelman

SQL Security Team, Microsoft

Comment: This indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: FYI: The PS script doesn't seem to handle umlauts (ü) in column names correctly. after using the script and importing the data, column names with umlauts do no longer container umlauts but "escaped" (?) characters. Which can be easily fixed manually... but still, depending on how long it will take you guys to get the normal function working again, might need a fix.